# How can I get a button's value when submitted in a form?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form with multiple buttons and also have a separate submit button.

When I click a button how can I disable this button and make the other button enabled? Like on/off conditions.

Also how can I get the value of the disabled button in the submitted form so I can store it in my database?

Comment: @Navas Next time, when you will ask a question , please dont forget to [Read This First](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: hi@Thomas,how can i get the multiple button values with jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that might help you: http://jsfiddle.net/XHBZf/417/

When a button is clicked the styles change on all the buttons to show that one is depressed and the others are still active.

The value of that button then goes into the text field which will be submitted along with the form.

When you come to implement you can set the input as `type="hidden"` and it will not show up in the form.

Comment: thanks for your answers dear..but when i submit the now only the form  value of clicked button are passed to  another page..

Comment: your codes are correct but something mismatch like my previous comments

Comment: Hi @navas you want the values of all the buttons? But the buttons have static text right? You should know what the values are without having to send them in the form.

Answer (score 1):

set id and name of the button = button1

$disabledButton = $_GET['id'];

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.prop`

```
$('#button1').click(function () {
        $('#button1').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#button2' ).prop( "disabled", false );
    });
});
```

Now you have to have your buttons with the `id='button1'` and `id='button2'`